# Read for inputs individually in C

Tags: c, input, bufferedinputstream

I want to read inputs individually. That means that I enter a character, press enter and then ask for the second input. The problem is that when the program asks me to input the character it asks for both at the same time.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Enter a character \n");

    char a = 0;
    a = getchar();

    printf("You entered: %c \n",a);

    putchar(a);

    printf("\n");

    char b[2];
    puts(b);
    gets(b);

    printf("You entered: %c \n",b[0]);

    puts(b);
}
```

Comment: Do not use `gets`, this is an accident waiting to happen. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Follow the link tor the full story on [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)  Using it with `char b[2];` is beyond foolhardy.

Comment: 1. The computer does exactly what you tell it to. Nothing more, nothing less. If you want to get one character at a time, you must use the right code to do so. 2. `getchar()` reads only one character. When the user types a character then presses enter, there are **two** characters in the input: the character you want plus a "new line" character. You must consume this newline character in order to continue wiht other input.

Comment: Note that the first `puts(b);` outputs indeterminate data; the array `b` is not initialized, so you've no idea what will be printed.  Also note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not just a `char`.  Assigning the value to a `char` will lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, within a while loop

```
char b[2];
int x;

while(b)
{
    for(x=0;x<2;x++)
    {
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",b[x]);
    printf("%c",b[x]);
    }
 b++;
}return;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.

First, and this is very important: Do not use `gets()` ever again. This is a
dangerous function: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Besides `gets` is not included in C11 any more.

Second, you need to understand what happens when you input data with the
keyboard. When you enter a text you have to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for the
reading routing to continue. The <kbd>ENTER</kbd> also gets stored in the input
buffer as the newline (`'\n'`) character. So if you enter *abc* the
buffer will contain<sup>1</sup>:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \n |
+---+---+---+----+
```

This is important to remember, because for example [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) stop reading from
the buffer when it encounters the newline character<sup>2</sup>. Other functions
like `scanf` may read the newline depending on the conversion specifier used.

You use `getchar`.

> *man getchar*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int fgetc(FILE *stream);
>
> int getc(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> int getchar(void);
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `fgetc()` reads the next character from stream and returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or `EOF` on end of file or error.
>
> `getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
>
> `getchar()` is equivalent to `getc(stdin)`.

it is clear from the documentation that `getchar()` reads **one** character
only. At this point it's important to notice that all reading functions like
`fgets`, `scanf`, etc. will first try to read from the input buffer and only
when the input buffer is empty and they still need to keep reading, then they
will wait for user input. That means if a previous read function left characters
in the input buffer, the next read function might not wait for user input,
because it might read from the input buffer.

So, let's say you entered <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The input buffer will
look like this:

```
+---+----+
| a | \n |
+---+----+
```

The input buffer will have at least 2 characters in it, `'a'` and the newline.
`getchar` reads the first and returns. The input buffer look now like this:

```
+----+
| \n |
+----+
```

Then you execute `gets(b);`, it will see that there are characters left in
the input buffer, hence it will read from it. It reads the newline and `gets`
stops reading, because `gets` stops reading, because of the newline that
was in the input buffer. `gets` didn't need to wait for user input. As
an user you have the impression that the `gets` call was skipped.

Finally:

```
char b[2];
puts(b);
```

This is undefined behaviour, because `b` is an uninitialized array, meaning that
the values `b[0]` and `b[1]` are undefined (unknown, they may be 0, or -2323 or
2829281, nobody knows). [`puts`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) expects a String. In C a string is sequence
of non-zero bytes that end with the value 0 (the so called `'\0'`-terminating
byte). `b` is not a string, so doing `puts(b)` yields undefined behaviour.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>I don't know if the input buffer also stores a `'\0'`-terminating
byte after the newline. In any case it is not important here.

<sup>2</sup>Provided that the destination buffer is large enough. If there is no
more space in the destination buffer, `fgets` stop reading anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use safe `fgets` instead of `gets`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char a[16];

    printf("1) Enter a character: \n");
    fgets ( a, sizeof (a), stdin );
    printf("1) You entered: %c \n",a[0]);
    puts(a);


    printf("2) Enter a character: \n");
    char b[16];
    fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin);
    printf("2) You entered: %c \n",b[0]);

    puts(b);
}
```

Input:

```
1
B
```

Output:

```
1) Enter a character: 
1) You entered: 1 
1

2) Enter a character: 
2) You entered: B 
B
```

Comment: It's much safer to do `fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin);`. If for some reason you change the dimension of `b` (let say to 10) and don't remember to change the `fgets`s (because they are apart by several lines), you might have a buffer overflow. Also `fgets` always stores is `'\0'`-terminated string, there is no point in reading 1 less byte.

Comment: @Pablo  Thank you!  Very good point! I have edited the example.